# Hyperlink at footer using itextSharp

Tags: itext

I need to put a hyperlink at the footer of my PDF generated using iTextSharp.

I know how to use PdfPageEventHelper to print some text in the footer but not putting a hyperlink.

```
    public class PdfHandlerEvents: PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        private PdfContentByte _cb;
        private BaseFont _bf;

        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            _cb = writer.DirectContent;
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            _bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

            _cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

            _cb.BeginText();
            _cb.SetFontAndSize(_bf, 10);
            _cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "More information", pageSize.GetRight(200), pageSize.GetBottom(30), 0);
            _cb.EndText();
        }
    }
```

How do I make the text "More information" a hyperlink?

Edited:

After the answer from Chris below, I have also figure out how to print image at the footer, here is the code:

```
            Image pic = Image.GetInstance(@"C:\someimage.jpg");
            pic.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
            pic.ScalePercent(25);

            PdfTemplate tpl = _cb.CreateTemplate(pic.Width, pic.Height);
            tpl.AddImage(pic);
            _cb.AddTemplate(tpl, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Document` object generally lets you work with abstract things like `Paragraph` and `Chunk` but in doing so you lose absolute positioning. The `PdfWriter` and `PdfContentByte` objects give you absolute positioning but you need to work with lower level objects like raw text.

Luckily there is a happy middle-ground object called `ColumnText` that should do what you're looking for. You can think of the `ColumnText` as basically a table and most people use it as a single column table so you can actually just think of it as a rectangle that you add objects to. See the comments in the code below for any questions.

```
public class PdfHandlerEvents : PdfPageEventHelper {
    private PdfContentByte _cb;
    private BaseFont _bf;

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        _cb = writer.DirectContent;
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

        _bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        //Create our ColumnText bound to the canvas
        var ct = new ColumnText(_cb);
        //Set the dimensions of our "box"
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(pageSize.GetRight(200), pageSize.GetBottom(30), pageSize.Right, pageSize.Bottom);
        //Create a new chunk with our text and font
        var c = new Chunk("More Information", new iTextSharp.text.Font(_bf, 10));
        //Set the chunk's action to a remote URL
        c.SetAction(new PdfAction("http://www.aol.com"));
        //Add the chunk to the ColumnText
        ct.AddElement(c);
        //Tell the ColumnText to draw itself
        ct.Go();

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Chris, it works and I have learnt so much from this code doing new tricks! Thanks!